# Повторная авторизация в NSURLSession с помощью делегата

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Два вопроса:

1. В каких случаях вызывается метод `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` делегата `NSURLSessionDelegate`? Если ответ на запрос пришел не с 2ХХ статус кодом?
2. Смогу ли я использовать это метод делегата для авторизации, если для повторного запроса мне необходимо обновить токен авторизации **@"ticket"** в теле запроса ?

   ```
   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
   NSError *error;
   NSDictionary *mapData = @{
                         @"userIdentity": @{
                                 @"ticket": [SecretStorage sharedInstance].ticket,
                                 @"hotelId": [SecretStorage sharedInstance].hotelId,
                                 @"language": @"ru"
                                 }
                         };
   NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"example.com"]
                                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                  timeoutInterval:60.f];
   [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setHTTPBody:postData];

   NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                           completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                               NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                               NSLog(@"%@", json);
                                           }];
   [dataTask resume];
   ```